# Slow Wi-Fi after update to tvOS 15

Tags: wifi, appletv, bug

After updating my AppleTV 4K to tvOS 15, my network speeds (as measured by Speedtest) drop from over 500 Mbps to around 100 Mbps (and intermittently much lower). I've rebooted my AppleTV and my network (both my eero Pro 6 and my cablemodem) several times, and have "forgotten" and re-added my Wi-Fi network on the AppleTV.

Does tvOS 15 have a networking bug? Are there other solutions I should try?

Comment: Is this causing a practical problem? My "AppleTV" is inside an LG OLED TV, which only has 100-BaseT [who knows why they did that] & no issues with 4k broadcasts. https://www.cable.co.uk/broadband/guides/broadband-streaming/ claims AppleTV is the heaviest requirement at 41mbps

Comment: @Tetsujin Yes, _dramatically_ (all media starts blurry and there are intermittent sync losses with the HomePod mini speakers). It may be the the speed results are a symptom of something else (e.g. erratic throughput) so that aggregate speed alone is not the issue. YMMV.

Comment: (This is 4th gen AppleTV, right?) Are you using only the wifi connection or only the ethernet connection or both to the AppleTV? Try just the ethernet connection and check speed test again. If the throughput is still low, you have a networking issue; if it is near the 500Mbps range you were expecting, you have a wireless issue.

Comment: @mr.cook It’s an ATV issue. Other devices placed in the same location have excellent speeds, and I’m using Wi-Fi only (Ethernet is not possible).

Comment: I would run an Ethernet cable, even a long one, to test the speed as wifi is less stable always no matter how close a device is to the router. The other options are more drastic like resetting the ATV. You could check your router too and make sure the ATV is not blocked or restricted, but that really depends on how you have configured your network.

Comment: @mr.cook Not possible and in any case I use wifi so that would be irrelevant. I've tried all other devices in the same location and they show no change in speeds, so that's really not the first place to look for the issue. This plus the volume control bug suggest to me that there's an update needed to fix a few glitches in 15.

Comment: Then as a last effort before filing the bug(s) with Apple, I suggest a reset of the ATV. https://support.apple.com/guide/tv/reset-apple-tv-atvbf9db0a52/tvos

Comment: @mr.cook I'll wait for an OS update before I do that. Judging from the many issues with the latest updates (across the board, iOS, tvOS and macOS) I'm guessing there was some pressure to get this out before it was ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my experience and that of others with the same problem who I've spoken with, this was indeed a bug introduced in tvOS 15.0 that had (apparently) been fixed in 15.1 and has now returned in 15.2.